# Apache Solr on Azure

Tags: azure, solr, azure-hdinsight

Guys I am trying to install Apache Solr on an existing HDInsight cluster in azure. I am aware that solr can be installed using script action while provisioning the cluster, but I am not sure how to install solr on existing cluster. Need assistance.

Comment: Although it's recommended to install during cluster provisioning, IS there no way we can install solr on existing HDInsight cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They just announced today that you can now [apply cluster customizations to a running cluster](https://azure.microsoft.com/blog/azure-hdinsight-enables-customizations-to-live-running-clusters/).

See the [Solr cluster customization](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-hadoop-solr-install/) page.

Manually installing things on a running cluster (instead of using a cluster customization script) still isn't recommended. For one thing when one node needs to be taken down for maintenance the new node will come back up without the custom software installed. Second the cluster customization script communicates to Azure support what changes you have made to the cluster when you open a support case.